# extract a value from returned json

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, json.net

I have the following json return from the url:

```
{"token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":"3599","expires_on":"1433956297","not_before":"1433952397","resource":"https://outlook.office365.com/","access_token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ik1uQ19WWmNBVGZNNXBPWWlKSE1iYTlnb0VLWSIsImtpZCI6Ik1uQ19WWmNBVGZNNXBPWWlKSE1iYTlnb0VLWSJ9.eyJhdWQi????...."
```

I want to extract the `access_token` in ASP.NET VB, but no matter what I try, it generates error. What is the the best solution to do this?

This is my code:

```
Dim parsedObject = JObject.Parse(<json string>)
Dim docs = parsedObject("access_token")

For Each doc In docs
    Dim snippet As String = doc("access_token")
Next

label1.text = snippet
```

Comment: I'm unclear from your example... the return JSON, does it contain a single instance of the object, or an array of the object?

Comment: In other words, do you *know* there will only be one instance of "access_token", or might it occur multiple times in the JSON you get back?

Answer (score 0):

Your variable *snippet* is not accessible outside the loop: you can't access it outside of the loop.

Step thru your debugger: you need to figure out what the value and data type of *docs* are before you go any further. Since you're already referring to the value of "access_token" from *docs*, you probably can't get it again from the resultant value. I'm guessing it should just give you a string; it's hard to say without the error.